# Convert List<object> to generic param T, when generic method is call with T is of type List<myClass>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In a generic method like : `public T getList<T>()`,
I have a List and I need to convert it in type T to return it.

```
public T getList<T>()
{
    List<object> someObjects = getListObject();  // Get object from any where.
    return (dynamic)someObjects;   // Casting don't work
}
```

I call this method with T is of type `List<myClass>`, like this :

```
List<myClass> myClassList = getList<List<myClass>>()
```

Then I have a runtime exception who said that I can't convert `List<object>` to `List<myClass>`
It's normal, and I understand why.

But how can I do someting like that ?

I have tryed same thing with this method :

```
public List<T> getList<T>()
{
    List<object> someObjects = getListObject();  // Get object from any where.
    return (dynamic)someObjects.OfType<T>.ToList<T>;   // that work good
}
```

Now I call this method with T is of type `myClass`, like this :

```
List<myClass> myClassObjects = getList<myClass>()
```

It work good, but I need to use this method with T is of type `List<myClass>`

Comment: So what do you expect your method to do if someone passes in `int` as the generic argument, or `string`, or `Dictionary<string, CustomClass>`?  If your method can only return a list, and not any type, then *it should return a list* and not a generic type.

Comment: It's because I very simplified my question to focus only on that point.  There is some tests based `value.GetType()` before returning whatever.

Comment: Rather than writing the method to say it can return any type, and just failing at runtime if it's not the *one* type that's supported, you should write the method *so that it always returns that one type*, and *can't* fail at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `getList<T>` method is defined slightly wrong.  You want to return a generic list.  I made your implementation static, but it doesn't need to be.  The `getList<T>` method can be an instance method as well.

Hopefully, this is what you need:

```
public class TemplateExamples
{
    public static List<T> getList<T>()
    {
        List<T> someObjects = new List<T>();
        return someObjects;   
    }
}
```

here's an example of using it:

```
public class TestTemplateExamples
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var intList = TemplateExamples.getList<int>();
        var stringList = TemplateExamples.getList<string>();
        var templateList = TemplateExamples.getList<TemplateExamples>();
    }
}
```

Thnx

Comment: No, I want use it like this : `var intList = TemplateExamples.getList<List<int>>();` or `var stringList = TemplateExamples.getList<List<string>>();`  It is important to have `List<>` specified inside the `<T>`

Comment: I'm not sure why you need it that way.  Can you add more details why its important to have ````List<int>```` as the type?

Comment: I don’t know why but this is the most confusing question I ever read.

Comment: @Neil.Work are you referring to my question in the comment or the original posted question?

Comment: @i.do.stuff The original question I find confusing.  I would have thought your answer sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

For [reasons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/30/whats-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility/), a given `List<object>` can be assigned or cast to a `List<T>` but you can cast each element in a `List<object>` to `T` and if there are no errors, return that.

However, you can't easily get at the generic type parameter of the type passed in, so you need to pass in the element type:

```
public List<T> getList<T>() {
    List<object> someObjects = getListObject();  // Get object from any where.
    return someObjects.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

This uses the LINQ `Cast` method to cast each element and creates a new `List<T>` from the result.